# Saxon processor is not accepting this statement (throwing error)

Tags: xslt, saxon

Saxon XSLT 2.0 processor is throwing the below error

Error on line 2 column 32:

SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Element type "xsl:value-of" must be followed by
either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

```
<xsl:when test="contains(., ',')">
<xsl:value-of select="concat('"', ., '"')"/>
</xsl:when>
```

It is showing error at the first double quotes inside the concat function. 
I am not sure if it is specific to saxon processor or I am wrong with basic XSLT syntax.
Can anyone please help me to rectify this error. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape double quotes:

```
<xsl:when test="contains(., ',')">
<xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;', ., '&quot;')"/>
</xsl:when>
```